# Issue with duplicate last names/cannot find object

Tags: r

Recent excel graduate trying to transition to R, so am very new to this.

I am trying to create a player based sports model. However, when trying to print the code I have already written, R is conflating players with the same last name (using dplyr). Essentially it has created two columns (player_last_name.x and player_last_name.y), and has merged these players stats. My first thoughts were to merge the first and last name columns into one. However, not sure how R goes with merging categorical data.

Also, R seems to not be able to find my third variable in season_TOG.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

````
disp <- playerdata %>%
  group_by(player_first_name, player_last_name)%>%
  summarise(season_disposals = sum(disposals))%>%
  

games <- playerdata %>%
  group_by(player_first_name, player_last_name) %>%
  summarise(season_game_count = n_distinct(match_round))%>%

TOG <- playerdata %>%
  group_by(player_first_name, player_last_name)%>%
  summarise(season_TOG = sum(time_on_ground_percentage))%>%

PropModel_df <- merge(disp, games, TOG, by="player_first_name", "player_last_name")%>%

PropModel_df <- transform(PropModel_df, avg_disp = season_disposals/season_game_count)%>%

PropModel_df <- transform(PropModel_df, avg_TOG = season_TOG/season_game_count)%>%

print(PropModel_df)```

```Error in eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) : 
object 'season_TOG' not found```
````

Comment: Typo: `by="player_first_name", "player_last_name"` should be `by=c("player_first_name", "player_last_name")` (i.e., group the two in a `c(..)` vector). Actually, it's worse ... one cannot `merge` three frames in one call, perhaps `df <- Reduce(function(a, b) merge(a, b, by=c(...)), list(disp, games, TOG))`, though you're going to have a mess of `.x`/`.y` column names.

Comment: You have a trailing pipe `%>%` at the end of the three lines that define and update `PropModel_df`.  I suspect you are misusing the pipe.  Try deleting the pipes.  If that doesn't give you what you want, please supply a minimal reproducible example, including input data and expected output.  Also @r2evans' comment is relevant.

Comment: I'm curious: why are you loading and using `dplyr`, but use `merge` and `transform`? If you're using tidy packages, you should really be using `inner_join` and `mutate`.

Comment: This code is not even close to being parse-able, there are several areas where an error should exist. When you are troubleshooting code, ***don't run all of it at once***, you should be stepping through expression-by-expression to see what fails. With that, you won't get past the assignment to `disp` as it'll complain, perhaps `could not find function "%>%<-"`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three clear issues here.

1. Your code is not parse-able: you have extra `%>%` in several points of your code. It might be that this is just an artifact of your question, and you reduced some otherwise unnecessary portions of your code but didn't clean up your pipes ... in which case thank you for reducing your code, but please *try* your reduced code before posting in the question.
2. `merge` accepts exactly two frames to join, so your

   ```r
   PropModel_df <- merge(disp, games, TOG, by="player_first_name", "player_last_name")
   ```

   will fail by that notion. You'll need to merge the first two (`merge(disp, games, by=...)` and then merge those results with `TOG`.
3. When you join using multiple fields, you need to include them in a single-vector. Your code (adjusted for #2):

   ```r
   PropModel_df <- merge(disp, games, by="player_first_name", "player_last_name")
   ```

   should be

   ```r
   PropModel_df <- merge(disp, games, by = c("player_first_name", "player_last_name"))
   ```

   Further detail: when arguments are provided without names, they are assigned by *position*. Because [`merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) arguments are

   ```r
        merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)),
              by.x = by, by.y = by, all = FALSE, all.x = all, all.y = all,
              sort = TRUE, suffixes = c(".x",".y"), no.dups = TRUE,
              incomparables = NULL, ...)
   ```

   this is the apparent argument names for your call:

   ```r
   merge(x = disp, y = games, by = "player_first_name", by.x = "player_last_name")
   ```

   which is (I believe) not what you intend.